# AdSense Revenue only appearing with one dimension on certain days

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, adsense

I have an API importer that runs through each day for four different accounts (same user login). It uses the same set of dimensions and metrics for each account.

On random days, for just one account, the AdSense revenue will be 0, but pageviews will appear. When I replicate in the API explorer, I see that AdSense revenue will appear when I have only `one dimension`.

Two strange things:

1. Revenue is greater than 0 on certain days. If we hit the API at random times, it will provide the AdSense revenue with all dimensions. Other times it won't.
2. Adsense revenue returning with one dimension in the API explorer.

It's not the issue if the API breaking with AdSesne, because it does appear from time to time. We know it's getting revenue, just missing from the API.

Anyone seen this before? It's quite frustrating.

Thanks!